# While Loop - Not Equal - Python, Not Evaluating Correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Created a little program that generates two values between 1 and 10 (inclusive), and prompts the user to find the sum as an answer.

I'm trying to use a while loop here. It seems that the code "while (numb1 + numb2 != answer)" will always evaluate to true (even when false), and so the loop never exits.

Wondering what I might have missed? Would appreciate any input!

```
import random
numb1 = random.randint(1,10)
numb2 = random.randint(1,10)

print('What is: ', numb1, ' + ', numb2, '?')
answer = input('Answer: ')

while (numb1 + numb2 != answer):
    print('Incorrect, try again!')
    answer = input('Answer: ')
print('Correct!')
```

Comment: `input` returns a string, but `numb1` and `numb2` are integers.  Cast to an int before comparing: `answer = int(input('Answer: '))`

Comment: That's it, thanks! I thought "input" was for integers and "raw_input" was for strings. Guess I misunderstood this. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`answer` is a `str` while `numb1` and `numb2` are `int`s.

```
>>> 1 == "1"
False
```

Do this:

```
while numb1 + numb2 != int(answer):
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you comparing `int` values with `str` values, which **cannot** be equal in any case.

Before comparison convert `answer` to `int` with

```
answer = int(input('Answer: '))
```